# How can I have a .bat run on startup in the background

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, command-line

How can I have a .bat file run on startup in the background on a windows computer? Also I'm not the admin, so I have to do it without admin priveleges. Its an old computer I bought at a garage sale.

Comment: You can do that with Task Scheduler, but you may the work Admin to set it up for you. It will work if properly set up.

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be configuring this computer to run tasks on startup.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about circumventing network security/policies at an institution.

Comment: @KovyJacob That's malicious intent and a prosecutable crime. Why not do this on your personal computer or rent a server in an area with a low kw/hr cost? Libraries and schools often have their PC's OS reset to a fresh image _(e.g. no changes are kept)_ in the early morning hours, but let's assume their PC's don't: libraries don't make a lot of money and serve their community with free education and knowledge, so if you manage to do this, it's not victimless, as the whole community pays for it _(high utility use, premature equipment failures, etc.)_.

Comment: @JW0914 People just use library computers for web browsing so they don't need lots of cpu, and the gov't pays

Comment: Regarding your edit: Given the information you've already given, we do not believe you.

Comment: @KovyJacob Who pays the local government - taxpayers from the community, with the bulk being from local taxes paid by the community for which the library serves; the tax percentage amount they receive is quite small comparable to everything city taxes pay for _(likely <1% - you can find out how much by contacting the library's treasurer and/or the city's treasurer at City Hall)_.

Comment: @JW0914 Its not like they would spend it wisely otherwise; they sset aside certain amounts of money to burn on pointless endevaours.

Comment: @KovyJacob I'm sorry, we do not assume people are making light of our efforts here and joking. You have asked us to help you commit a malicious act for your own financial benefit on public computers. This is wrong and you ought to be ashamed for seriously considering doing this, and for asking us to aid you. This isn't a joking matter, and your failure to admit you were wrong and take this error seriously is frustrating.

Comment: @music2myear I hear what you are saying that this wasn't the right forum to ask this and I shouldn't be wasting people's time for this type of thing. I still don't think that the idea is wrong, but this definetly isn't the right forum.

Answer (score 3):

Considering your latest comment on your initial post, the reason for your question sounds malicious. Having a miner running on a PC where it is not especially permitted may be in conflict with local law and/or library authorities. On top it will greatly impact it's performance as well as increase power consumption, which you're using to generate personal profit from.

That said, this is malicious intent, which is why this question should be closed by a moderator.